# How to Pad several rows of string in a listbox in C#

Tags: c#

So I have been trying to display my row of strings in the listbox. However, no matter what I try the padding of each of the string seems screwed up.
What should I do? Anyone know a way to pad strings correctly in a listbox?

I tried altering values of the formatting function I am currently using, as it worked previously for me. I changed the values from +ve to -ve, but it all just didn't add up. It wasn't functioning the way it should.

Here is the formatting code I used:

```
format = "{0, -30}{1, -30}{2, -30}{3, -30}{4, -30}{5, -30}";
listBoxLandowners.Items.Add(String.Format(format, "Landowner ID", "First Name", "Last Name", "City", "Street", "Street Number"));

SQL.selectQuery("select * from Landowner", null, null);
if(SQL.read.HasRows)
{
     while(SQL.read.Read())
                {
                    _landID = SQL.read[0].ToString();
                    _fName= SQL.read[1].ToString();
                    _lName = SQL.read[2].ToString();
                    _city = SQL.read[3].ToString();
                    _street = SQL.read[4].ToString();
                    _streetNum = SQL.read[5].ToString();
                    listBoxLandowners.Items.Add(String.Format(format, _landID, 
                    _fName, _lName,_city, _street, _streetNum));
                }
            }
```

Actual outcome:
[image]

I want it to pad correctly and neatly, but couldn't get it to work.
Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not use a `ListView` instead, which is meant for this kind of columnar display.

Comment: What kind of “listbox” are you using? UWP? ASP.NET? Show your XAML or .cshtml.

Comment: With a proportional font a character like 'w' is going to take more room than 'i'. String padding cant overcome that

Comment: The quickest fix is to use a fixed-width font like Courier New. However you really shouldn't be using a ListBox for multi-column display (except in MS Access, which supports multiple columns). In WinForms you should use a DataGrid or a ListView.

Comment: Alright, ill try using a listview.

Comment: Sorry if this is a noob question, but. What is the difference between listview and listbox? Does Listview also allow for user interactions? like if they click on a row it does something else.

Answer (score 0):

In WinForms, ListBox is not a very good control for multiple columns.

Try using a ListView in Details mode.

```
var listviewLandOwners = new ListView();
listviewLandOwners.View = View.Details;
```

When in this mode, the first column is controlled by the `Text` property of the ListViewItem. The second column is controlled by `SubItems[0]`. The third is `SubItems[1]`. Etc. So your loop might look like this:

```
while(SQL.read.Read())
{
    var newItem = listviewLandowners.Items.Add(SQL.read[1].ToString());
    newItem.SubItems.Add(SQL.read[2].ToString());
    newItem.SubItems.Add(SQL.read[3].ToString());
    newItem.SubItems.Add(SQL.read[4].ToString());
    newItem.SubItems.Add(SQL.read[5].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Using it in detail mode doesn't display anything. But when using the View.List it works, but the same problem still arises.